# Mathcounts 2014 National Team #8

Tags: probability, contest-math

[image: MATHCOUNTS 2014 National Team round #8]

I encountered this problem when practicing with past competition problems. Since 1-6 contains 3 even, 3 odd and 3 primes (2,3,5), each branch obviously has $\dfrac{1}{2}$ probability to happen. It is easy to compute that in each cycle the probability to Obtain a 'B', 'N' and 'A' is $P(B)=\frac{1}{8}$, $P(N)=\dfrac{1}{4}$ and $P(A)=\dfrac{1}{2}$, with the rest $\dfrac{1}{8}$ to reset to start without writing any letter, cause a retry chance. So overall, the chance of getting these letters are

$$\begin{cases}
    P(B)=\frac{1}{8}\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8^{2}}+\cdots\right)=\frac{1}{7}\\
    P(N)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8^{2}}+\cdots\right)=\frac{2}{7}\\
    P(A)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8^{2}}+\cdots\right)=\frac{4}{7}\\
\end{cases}$$

They add up to 1, as the machine eventually will split one of the three. So the probability to get BANANA should be

$$\frac{1}{7}\cdot\frac{4}{7}\cdot\frac{2}{7}\cdot\frac{4}{7}\cdot\frac{2}{7}\cdot\frac{4}{7}=\frac{256}{117649}$$

However the answer key is $\dfrac{27}{15625}$, which I totally have no clue where it comes from. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have computed $P(N)$ and $P(B)$ wrong: note that there is no third roll, only two rolls in a cycle. Carefully examining the flowchart nets you $P(A) = 1/2, P(B) = 1/6, P(N) = 1/6$ and $P(\text{reset}) = 1/6$, which gives the right answer, as excluding resets we get $P(A) = 3/5, P(B) = 1/5, P(N) = 1/5$.

Comment: Oh, right! Dammit... no third roll. Thanks a lot buddy! I am so hopeless...